# Extends twig IF

Tags: symfony, twig, extends

I know there was similarly topic to this one but I still can't fix this problem..

I want to `{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}` but when user is logged in I want to `{% extends '::**newlayout**.html.twig' %}`

Of course `{% if app.user %}{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}{% else %}{% extends '::newlayout.html.twig' %}` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with [Conditional Inheritance](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html#conditional-inheritance):

```
{% extends app.user ? '::layout.html.twig' : '::newlayout.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much brother! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY') %}
    {% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}
{% else %}
    {% extends '::newlayout.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```